# I need vlookup formula to extract data from 3 excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-office, vlookup

I have a use case with excel. I have three different excel sheets namely `raw data`, `reference`, `report` as below. Report sheet contains the total expense of each person (which needs to be calculated), reference sheet contains expense category for each person and raw data sheet contains expense name and expense value. I need to find the total expense of each person(column B in the report sheet)  using `VLOOKUP` or any other formula.

I need single  formula to find the total expense of each person using three sheets. I am aware of joins adn importing data in excel. But, I want it to be implemented with formula only.

[image: raw_data]

Raw_data

[image: reference]

Reference sheet

[image: report]

Report

Answer (score 1):

You may create column C on your Raw Data sheet by using INDEX + MATCH function to get names from column A of the your reference sheet;

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$13,MATCH(A1,$B$2:$B$13,0),0)
```

In this forumula $A$2:$A$13 and $B$2:$B$13 should be selected from reference data excel while A1 should be from raw data excel. Then you can instert following formula to your report excel;

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$13,$A$3:$A$13,A2)
```

In this formula $C$2:$C$13 and $A$3:$A$13 should come from your raw data and A2 should set for report excel.

I hope it is clear to you. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, @Omur Thanks for the answer. index function worked perfectly. But, the SUMIFS function is giving incorrect results as 0.

Comment: Hi @Omur, I just replaced C with A and A with C in the SUMIFS function. It worked perfectly. But, Isn't there any way to implement in a single formula without using the index function in the rawdata sheet? What I wanted to do is, without touching the reference sheet and raw data, can we use a single formula in the report sheet. Or is there any way to include that index function in the SUMIFS function? I want a single shot formula to achieve this result without using that index function in the rawdata sheet. Please help

Comment: Hi Omur. Below is sample formula

=SUMIFS([rawdata.xlsx]Sheet1!B:B,INDEX([reference.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(A1,[reference.xlsx]Sheet1!B:B,0),0),A2)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have office 365, the above can be easily done

```
=SUM(SUMIF($A$2:$A$7,FILTER($E$2:$E$7,$D$2:$D$7=G2),$B$2:$B$7))
```

Sample data below

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywkTo.png)

Comment: . Thanks, @rangraj for the answer. I tried to implement your answer. But it is throwing me an error saying an invalid function. Below is the formula that I implemented.

=SUM(SUMIF([rawdata.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A,FILTER([reference.xlsx]Sheet1!B:B,[reference.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A=A2),[rawdata.xlsx]Sheet1!B:B))

Comment: which version of excel are you using ?

Comment: microsoft office 2010

Comment: Thats too old, let me try to make some formula thats compatible with 2010

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(A2=RIGHT(Raw_data!A:A,1),Raw_data!B:B,0))
```

Comment: Hi @Robert. I also have a reference sheet that shows the expense category for a person. Three sheets are dependent on each other. There is no way to ignore the reference sheet.

Comment: Hi @robert The data I have given in the post is just sample data. Here partial match can give results. But in my use case, no data matches either partisslly or completely with each other